# Uncertainty Principle state space of a single particle/object?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, mathematics, quantum-states

My question is about **mathematics in the context of physics**

Imagine a series of quantum states of a single particle:

In the first state the particle has a certain position but an uncertain momentum

In the last state the particle has an uncertain position but a certain momentum

Also imagine all other possible (obeying the [Uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)) states in between

What is the mathematical space that describes all those possible states (if we disregard all other information about the particle)?

Is this space applicable only to Quantum Mechanics or to any other physical system with a similar tradeoff? By "similar tradeoffs" I mean cases like this:

> a narrow spread of possible outcomes for one experiment necessarily implies a wide spread of possible outcomes for another

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state

**P.S.: A similar question(s)**

[What is the single particle Hilbert space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30751/what-is-the-single-particle-hilbert-space) is a similar question, but it talks not only about position and momentum but about all other information too

But I am only interested in the former

Also I've seen this "[Uncertainty Principle for a Totally Localized Particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/uncertainty-principle-for-a-totally-localized-particle)" post

Comment: as to applicability , see this  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-64539-7

Comment: The space you want is $L^2({\mathbb R}^1)$.

Comment: Square-integrable functions (L2), Lebesgue spaces, on a real line (R1)? Thank you, got it!... Also I heard about the p-norms, PBS Infinite Series did a video on them... Thank you very much!!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ineO1tIyPfM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Imagine a series of quantum states of a single particle:
>
> In the first state the particle has a certain position but an uncertain momentum
>
> In the last state the particle has an uncertain position but a certain momentum
>
> Also imagine all other possible (obeying the Uncertainty principle) states in between
>
> What is the mathematical space that describes all those possible states (if we disregard all other information about the particle)?

States aren't uniquely determined by their position and momentum uncertainties, so there isn't a unique mathematical description of the series of states you are describing.

However, as you have alluded to, quantum states can be described as elements of [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) even if there isn't a unique way to mathematically move between such states.

As for this quote

> a narrow spread of possible outcomes for one experiment necessarily implies a wide spread of possible outcomes for another

I think more needs to be said. I would instead say

> a **sufficiently** narrow spread of possible outcomes for one experiment necessarily implies a wide spread of possible outcomes for another

If the quantum state is right up against an uncertainty principle limit, then yes, narrowing the uncertainty of one observable would necessarily mean that the uncertainty of another observable would have to widen. However, if a state is not near this limit, then narrowing one uncertainty would not need to be accompanied with the widening of another. This further points to the idea that one cannot determine a unique description of the series of states that you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and I got the last point)! As I understand you I didn't describe a state or even a special (degeneracy) case of it and it doesn't create any meaningful space of states. One question remains: what would be this space of "non-states" anyway? But maybe this question is then outside of physics and purely mathematical... thank you again(!)

Comment: @AxidUbish I don't think I understand your question. I didn't say anything in my answer about "non-states". I am saying actual states are not uniquely determined by their uncertainties in position and momentum, so it doesn't make sense to have a series of states where that's the only thing that varies. You would need to bring in other criteria to uniquely describe this series of states.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see one of your edits: << even if there isn't a unique way to mathematically move between such states. >> So in order for my question to make sense I should specify the "order" of such states, will it help (will the "order" serve as a way to move between them)? Let's say I want to move from the most certain position to the most uncertain position and also exclude all states that are not "near the limit" (not affected by the uncertainty principle)

Comment: @AxidUbish Yes. The easiest way to do this would be to look at Gaussian wave packets that are at the minimum uncertainty. You can actually have the uncertainties as parameters of the equations, so you could easily imagine tuning them while requiring $\Delta x\Delta p=\hbar/2$.

Comment: So a "wave packet" is a more suiting word here than "state" (I could edit the post if it's needed!)? And what is the space or the structure of the solutions of the equation with those parameters? Or is it absolutely nothing special? Thank you in advance (and forget about editing the post, sorry for mentioning it, 'cause your answer quotes it and is based on the current version)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet